# how can i get input data from two dynamic form in react class component?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I'm new with react.js. I don't know how can I update the state by button and get the input data from dynamic form as a json array formate.

I'm facing the issue of `onchangehandle` event, here is my UI dynamic form, which I have created.
[image].

Here are two forms that are opening dynamical like add more.

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { Button, Container, Col, Form, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
    import { FaTrashAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
    import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';
    
    
    class Forms extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            // _id: "6196350112f781463c760aa0",
            // book_title: "",
            // book_authore: "",
            // book_overview: "",
            // book_category: "",
            // book_genre: "",
            // book_tag: "",
            // book_languages: "",
            // book_duration: "",
            // book_rating: 5,
            // book_publication: "",
            // book_created_date: "",
            // booksEpdf: "",
            // booksAudio: "",
            // book_rating_count: 0,
            // book_review: 0,
            // book_like: 0,
            video_data: [
                {
                   _id: "",
                    book_All_details: "",
                    number_of_chapters:"",
                    chapter: 1,
                    video_title: "",
                    description: "",
                    video_url: "",
                    video_image: "",
                    releaseDate: "",
                    subvideo_data: [
                        {
                            _id: "",
                            subchapterid:"",
                            subchapter: 1,
                            subvideo_title: "",
                            subdescription: "",
                            subvideo_url: "",
                            subvideo_image: "",
                            subreleaseDate: "",
                        },
                      
                    ],
            
                },
            
         
            ],
      
        }  
    }
    
        handleChange(event){
            this.setState({[event.target.video_title]:event.target.value})
            console.log(event)
                
        }
            
        //to add a tier
        addTClick = (i) => {
            const video_data = [...this.state.video_data];
            video_data[i].subvideo_data.push({ subvideo_title:"", subdescription:"",subvideo_url:"",subvideo_image:""});
            this.setState({ video_data });
            console.log(video_data)
        };
    
        //to remove a tier
        removeTClick = (i, idx) => {
            const video_data =  [...this.state.video_data];
            video_data[i].subvideo_data.splice(idx, 1);
            this.setState({ video_data });
        };
    
    
        //to add region and tier
        addFTClick = () => {
            const video_data = [...this.state.video_data];
            video_data.push({
                    number_of_chapters: "",
                    chapter: "",
                    video_title: "",
                    description: "",
                    video_url: "",
                    video_image: "",
                    subvideo_data: [{subvideo_title:"", subdescription:"",subvideo_url:"",subvideo_image:""} ]
                    });
                    this.setState({ video_data });
                };
    
        render() {
            const   removeFormFields =(i) =>{
            const video_data = [...this.state.video_data];
            video_data.splice(i, 1);
                this.setState({ video_data });
            }
    
        return (
            <Container>
                {this.state.video_data.map((video_datas, i) => (
                <form key={i}>
                      
                <div class="container" style={{background:'aqua'}}>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                        <label>Enter Chapter Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="number_of_chapters"
                                 onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                        value={this.state.number_of_chapters} 
                        class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
                    </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label>Title:</label>
                        <input type="text"              onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                        value={this.state.video_title} 
                            name="video_title" class="form-control"  placeholder="title" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                        <label>Description:</label>
                        <input type="text"               onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                        value={this.state.description} 
                            name="description"  class="form-control"  placeholder="authors" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Thambnail image:</label>
                    <input               onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                        value={this.state.video_image} 
                            name ="video_image" type="file" class="form-control"  />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Upload Video:</label>
                    <input               onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                        value={this.state.video_url} 
                            name="video_url" type="file" class="form-control pb-4" />
                </div> <br></br>
                {video_datas.subvideo_data.map((subvideo_datas, idx) => (
                    <div class="container bg-success py-2" key={idx}> 
                        <div className="main">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Title:</label>
                                <input type="text" ref="video_title"
                                 onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}   value={this.state.subvideo_title} 
                                    name="subvideo_title" class="form-control"  placeholder="title" />
                            </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Description:</label>
                                <input type="text"  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                                 value={this.state.subdescription}   name="subdescription" class="form-control"  placeholder="title" />
                            </div>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Thambnail image:</label>
                            <input  name ="subvideo_image"  onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                              value={this.state.subvideo_image} type="file" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Upload Video:</label>
                            <input  name="video_url" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} 
                              value={this.state.subvideo_url} type="file" class="form-control pb-4" />
                        </div> <br></br>
                        <Button  variant="danger"  onClick={this.removeTClick.bind(this, i, idx)}><FaTrashAlt style={{ marginRight:"5px"}}/>Remove</Button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        ))}
                        <div className="button-section" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                             <Button variant="link" className="addMoreBtn"onClick={this.addTClick.bind(this, i)}>+Add More </Button>
                        </div>
                        {
                            i? 
                            <Button  variant="danger" onClick={() => removeFormFields(i)}><FaTrashAlt style={{ marginRight:"5px"}}/>Remove</Button>
                            : null
                        }
                        </div>
                        </form>
                        ))}
                       <div className="button-section" style={{textAlign:"center"}}>
                            <Button className="addMoreBtn" onClick={this.addFTClick.bind(this)}>
                                    +Add chapter
                            </Button>
                        </div>
            </Container>
          );
      }
    }
    
    export default Forms;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, Container, Col, Form, InputGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FaTrashAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import Accordion from 'react-bootstrap/Accordion';

class Forms extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            video_data: [
                {
                    _id: "",
                    book_All_details: "",
                    number_of_chapters: "",
                    chapter: 1,
                    video_title: "",
                    description: "",
                    video_url: "",
                    video_image: "",
                    releaseDate: "",
                    subvideo_data: [
                        {
                            _id: "",
                            subchapterid: "",
                            subchapter: 1,
                            subvideo_title: "",
                            subdescription: "",
                            subvideo_url: "",
                            subvideo_image: "",
                            subreleaseDate: "",
                        },
                    ],
                }]
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.addFTClick = this.addFTClick.bind(this);
        this.addTClick = this.addTClick.bind(this);
        this.removeTClick = this.removeTClick.bind(this);
        this.removeFormFields = this.removeFormFields.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeSubVideo = this.handleChangeSubVideo.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event, index) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
            nextState[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
            return { video_data: nextState };
        });
    }

    handleChangeSubVideo(event, index, subIndex) {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
            nextState[index].subvideo_data[subIndex][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
            return { video_data: nextState };
        });
    }

    //to add a tier
    addTClick = (i) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
            nextState[i].subvideo_data.push({ subvideo_title: "", subdescription: "", subvideo_url: "", subvideo_image: "" });
            return { video_data: nextState };
        });
    };

    //to remove a tier
    removeTClick = (i, idx) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
            nextState[i].subvideo_data.splice(idx, 1);
            return { video_data: nextState };
        });
    };


    //to add region and tier
    addFTClick = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
            nextState.push({
                number_of_chapters: "",
                chapter: "",
                video_title: "",
                description: "",
                video_url: "",
                video_image: "",
                subvideo_data: [{ subvideo_title: "", subdescription: "", subvideo_url: "", subvideo_image: "" }]
            });
            return { video_data: nextState };
        });
    };

    removeFormFields = (i) => {
        this.setState(prevState => {
            const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
            nextState.splice(i, 1);
            return { video_data: nextState };
        });
    }

    render() {


        return (
            <Container>
                {this.state.video_data.map((video_datas, i) => (
                    <form key={i}>
                        <div class="container" style={{ background: 'aqua' }}>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label>Enter Chapter Name:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="number_of_chapters"
                                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, i)}
                                    value={this.state.number_of_chapters}
                                    class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Title:</label>
                                    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, i)}
                                        value={this.state.video_title}
                                        name="video_title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                    <label>Description:</label>
                                    <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, i)}
                                        value={this.state.description}
                                        name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="authors" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Thambnail image:</label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, i)}
                                    value={this.state.video_image}
                                    name="video_image" type="file" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Upload Video:</label>
                                <input onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, i)}
                                    value={this.state.video_url}
                                    name="video_url" type="file" class="form-control pb-4" />
                            </div> <br></br>
                            {video_datas.subvideo_data.map((subvideo_datas, idx) => (
                                <div class="container bg-success py-2" key={idx}>
                                    <div className="main">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                <label>Title:</label>
                                                <input type="text" ref="video_title"
                                                    onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeSubVideo(e, i, idx)} value={this.state.subvideo_title}
                                                    name="subvideo_title" class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                                <label>Description:</label>
                                                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeSubVideo(e, i, idx)}
                                                    value={this.state.subdescription} name="subdescription" class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Thambnail image:</label>
                                            <input name="subvideo_image" onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeSubVideo(e, i, idx)}
                                                value={this.state.subvideo_image} type="file" class="form-control" />
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Upload Video:</label>
                                            <input name="video_url" onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeSubVideo(e, i, idx)}
                                                value={this.state.subvideo_url} type="file" class="form-control pb-4" />
                                        </div> <br></br>
                                        <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => this.removeTClick(i, idx)}><FaTrashAlt style={{ marginRight: "5px" }} />Remove</Button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            ))}
                            <div className="button-section" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                                <Button variant="link" className="addMoreBtn" onClick={() => this.addTClick(i)}>+Add More </Button>
                            </div>
                            {
                                i ?
                                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => this.removeFormFields(i)}><FaTrashAlt style={{ marginRight: "5px" }} />Remove</Button>
                                    : null
                            }
                        </div>
                    </form>
                ))}
                <div className="button-section" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
                    <Button className="addMoreBtn" onClick={() => this.addFTClick()}>
                        +Add chapter
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for help me. but this is gain showing error of "ReferenceError: bind is not defined"

Comment: @Ashutokumar Sorry. I edited my answer

Comment: ReferenceError: addFTClick is not defined, now this is showing error now

Comment: 174 |     </form>
  175 | ))}
  176 | <div className="button-section" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
> 177 |     <Button className="addMoreBtn" onClick={addFTClick}>
      | ^  178 |         +Add chapter
  179 |     </Button>
  180 | </div>

Comment: I edited it again

Comment: okay thank you .let me check it again

Comment: sir again this is showing error of ReferenceError: handleChange is not defined

Comment: | <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  103 |     <label>Enter Chapter Name:</label>
  104 |     <input type="text" name="number_of_chapters"
> 105 |         onChange={() => handleChange(i)}
      | ^  106 |         value={this.state.number_of_chapters}
  107 |         class="form-control" placeholder="title" />
  108 | </div>

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: Please add a link to could be check online

Comment: ×
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: i dont know how can i  show live link url of localhost

Comment: here is error nowhandleChange(event, index) {
  43 |     this.setState(prevState => {
  44 |         const nextState = [...prevState.video_data];
> 45 |         nextState[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
     | ^  46 |         return { video_data: nextState };
  47 |     });
  48 | }

Comment: Check it again.

Comment: thank you so much sir, this is now working,only sub video datas are not updating in state

Comment: _id
:
""
subchapter
:
1
subchapterid
:
""
subdescription
:
""
subreleaseDate
:
""
subvideo_image
:
""
subvideo_title
:
""
subvideo_url
:

Comment: I edited the answer again for sub videos

Comment: yes sir, now this is solved my problem. thank you so much alot..

Comment: Your welcome. Please accept my answer.

Comment: and do you have any idea about, videoimage and video file and file  path upload take input??

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54549069/how-to-setstate-with-a-file-object

Comment: thanks sir ,there is only one file state, we have filepath  in an array element, how cain i get  file path??